# node.js + bluebird: resolving promise.all

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I got a function `requestJSON` that queries an external API and returns a (bluebird) promise.

**Problem:** `b` gets resolved before `c` is added to the list so the `promise.all` runs while only `a` and `b` are resolved.

**Code:**

```js
let promises = [];

// push promise a
promises.push(requestJSON(..));

// push promise b
promises.push(requestJSON(..).then((response) {
  // push promise c
  promises.push(requestJSON({foo: response.bar});
});

promises.all((data) => {
  console.log(data.length) // --> 2
});
```

**Question:** 
I couldn't come up with a really satisfying solution for this problem. Is there a node-way / best-practice?

**Possible solutions**

(I) Wrap `b` in another promise and resolve it inside `c.then`.
*Problem:* One extra promise that doesn't really do much except cluttering the code.

```js
let promises = [];

// push promise a
promises.push(requestJSON(..));

// push helper promise
promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  // push promise b
  promises.push(requestJSON(..).then((response) {
    // push promise c
    promises.push(requestJSON({foo: response.bar});
    // resolve helper promise
    resolve();
  }).catch(..);
}));


promises.all((data) => {
  console.log(data.length) // --> 4
});
```

(II) Put everything inside `b.then`.
*Problem:* There's no semantic reason to place `a` and `promise.all` inside `b` + that solution reminds me of the pre-promise callback madness.

```js
let promises = [];

// push promise b
promises.push(requestJSON(..).then((response) {
  // push promise a
  promises.push(requestJSON(..));

  // push promise c
  promises.push(requestJSON({foo: response.bar});
  
  promises.all((data) => {
    console.log(data.length) // --> 3
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must return something from a `.then` callback. Either a value (then the promise is considered resolved) or another promise, if you want to continue waiting for something else.

```
let promises = [
    requestJSON(/* [1] */),
    requestJSON(/* [2] */).then(response => {
        return requestJSON(/* [3] */);
    })
];

// this waits for [1] and [3]
promises.all(promises).then(results => {
    console.log(data.length);
});
```

Your code did not return anything from the `.then()`. So the function return value is `undefined` and the promise gets settled with `undefined` as the result.

The above can be written as (note the implicit `return` in arrow functions that don't have a full body):

```
let promises = [
    requestJSON(/* [1] */),
    requestJSON(/* [2] */).then(response => requestJSON(/* [3] */))
];

promises.all(promises).then(results => console.log(data.length));
```

Comment: wow, I didn't know that you could return a promise inside then that you want to wait for, thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can build a chain that consists of as many promises as you like, all  resolving one after the other. One way to use this is `var p = dataArray.reduce( (chain, item) => asyncFunction(item), Promise.resolve());` This daisy-chains all items in the array, so that they are all processed in sequence. Starting with an blank promise `Promise.resolve()`, and returning a single promise `p` that resolves when the last item is done.